# Replacing the JSON from API with HTML in the Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, headless-cms

I have a simple **Vite+Vue.js** project in which I am importing data from headless-cms Wordpress using REST API and JSON. It should take and display titles and content of the posts (including imgs when they occure). I'm stuck because all the data on the page display like HTML, i.e. it contains HTML elements, but of course are JSON. Is there any way to convert it to plain HTML? I've tried filtering it with "replacer" method, but for all elements and situations it would take ages.

[Screenshot of how data display on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIv4m.png)

My component template:

```
<template>
<h1>Posts</h1>
<div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="posts">
    <h2> {{ post.title.rendered }} </h2>
    <div> {{ post.content.rendered }} </div>
</div>
```

My script in that component:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
            message: String,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        fetch('https://my-url-here.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.posts = data)
        .then(err => console.log(err)) 
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: `.then(err => console.log(err))` will ***always*** log `undefined`, because the previous `then()` returns `undefined`. The result of an assignment is `undefined`, regardless of what you're assigning. You probably meant `.catch(err => console.log(err))`.

Comment: thanks! yes I meant ```.catch``` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `v-html`

```
<template>
<h1>Posts</h1>
<div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="posts">
    <h2> {{ post.title.rendered }} </h2>
    <div v-html="post.content.rendered"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Didn't think its so simple